# Question regarding validation rules

Tags: validation, junction-object, order-of-execution

I have a junction object(volunteer hour) between volunteer job(custom) and contact(standard). whenever i try to save a record in volunteer hour, system triggers a validation rule of volunteer job. is this a normal execution? or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: That sounds like a workflow or a trigger is being used to update the related object. I'd look around for anything thats calling an update.

Comment: Or, -- RSF field on `Volunteer_Job__c` against child `Volunteer_Hour`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check before trigger on volunteer job and any workflow field update or after trigger on the volunteer hour object which could cause the validation rule to fire on volunteer job.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, there must be a trigger/workflow rule on your junction object which is updating the "volunteer job" record. That's the reason, the junction object update is causing the validation rule on volunteer job object to run.